# Probability that an accident next year

Tags: probability

Problem:
There are 1000 road interceptions. In 10 years, 130 accidents were recorded. What is the probability of having an accident next year?

I think we should divide 130/100 because this way we find the number of accidents per year. And then diving that by 1000. Does this sound correct? Or I need to use Poisson`s distribution? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well the number of intersections, unless there is something else missing in the question, is useless info.

A common model for number of accidents over time $t$ is $Poisson(\lambda t)$. If there are $1000$ roads, it we may model each as $Poisson(\lambda_i t)$, but it is an unnecessary complication since total accidents is $\sum_i^{1000} Poisson(\lambda_i t)=Poisson\left(\left(\sum_i^{1000}\lambda_i\right) t\right)$.

If we measure $t$ in years, then we can estimate $\hat\lambda*10=130$, so expected accidents per year (any year, including next year) is $E(X)$ where $X\sim Poisson(\hat\lambda)$, i.e. $13$.

But we want chance of any accident, which is $P(X>0) = 1-P(X=0) = 1-e^{-13}$, which is very close to certainty.